# Magento : Check if two conditions are true (category view)

Tags: magento-1.9, if, category-view

I am trying to check if two conditions are true in the Magento category view file. Specifically if parent id = 1 and if category name = Nike.

Can someone please suggest how I can update the code below to get this working?

```
<?php if ($_category->getParentCategory()->getId() == 1) && ($_category->getName() == 'Nike'): ?>
    <p>Then show this</p> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Please don't use this kind of fix. Create an attribute of category and on that attribute apply condition which show and hide your div or functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if condition syntax is wrong. You use

```
if ($_category->getParentCategory()->getId() == 1) && ($_category->getName() == 'Nike'):
```

In this code, your if statement parenthesis ends before && operator.

The correct syntax is :

```
if ($_category->getParentCategory()->getId() == 1 && $_category->getName() == 'Nike'):
```